# Custom function name using unique number

Tags: php, jquery, uniqueidentifier

I am using a number of HTML5 audio players on one page and I need a means to control them individually. I have so far been using:

```
<?php $unique = uniqid(); ?>
```

to generate a unique number. I have them been able to successfully apply this to my player:

```
<button class="bb-play" onClick="play-<?php echo $unique; ?>()">Play</button>
```

I am able to apply this within some jQuery, within the function as follows:

```
function play() { document.getElementById('player-<?php echo $unique; ?>').play(); }
```

My question is, where my unique number is say **56f295fbe6be3** how can get I get the function **play()** to appear instead as **play-56f295fbe6be3()** ?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to write a function with a unique number in its name is a bad approach. You should rather write a unique function that is able to handle them all.

```
<script>
    function play(that) {
        var playerId = that.id;
        document.getElementById('player-' + playerId).play();
    }
</script>
<button class="bb-play" id="<?php echo $unique; ?>" onClick="play(this)">Play</button>
```

From a semantic perspective, we're assigning to the `<button>` element an attribute that says what's the player id and it would make more sense to put it into a data attribute. It comes easier to use jQuery then:

```
<button class="bb-play" data-player-id="player-<?php echo $unique; ?>">Play</button>

<script>
    $("button.bb-play").click(function(){
        var playerId = $(this).data('playerId');
        $("#" + playerId).play();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't be
    id="player-<?php echo $unique; ?>"
?

Comment: Semantic... if the button is just the play button and the actual *player* is another element, it shouldn't have an id like "player-". Actually, it would make sense to move it to a data attribute, something like `data-player-id=<?php echo $unique; ?>` so you're explicitly giving this element an attribute stating what's the *player id*

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<button class="bb-play" onClick="play(<?php echo $unique; ?>);">Play</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function play(id) { document.getElementById('player-'+id).play(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the buttons and the player are places inside the same parent element, you could work without id's.

```
<div class="player">
    <media .../>
    <button class="bb-play">Play</button>
</div>
```

and the js code

```
$('.bb-play').on('click', function() {
    $('media', $(this).closest('.player')).get(0).play();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass the id number as a variable to the function?

```
function play_video(id) {
    document.getElementById('video-' + id).play();
}
```

And in the HTML use:

```
onClick="play_video(<?php echo $unique; ?>)" id="video-<?php echo $unique; ?>"

// onClick="play_video(56f295fbe6be3)" id="56f295fbe6be3"
```

Then you can just use `play_video()` for all videos.